# Conditions for Central Limit Theorem

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem

I want to apply this version of Central limit theorem for triangular arrays. I'm interested only on condition $2$.

> Let $\{X_{n,i}:1\leq i \leq d_n\}$ be a triangular array of mean zero
>   random variables. Denote the strong mixing coefficient corresponding
>   to the $n$th row by $\alpha_n$. Define     $$S_{n,k,a}=\sum_{i=a}^{a+k-1}
>  X_{n,i} ; \quad T_{n,k,a}=k^{-1/2}\sum_{i=a}^{a+k-1} X_{n,i}; \quad
>  \text{and  }\ \sigma_{n,k,a}^2=Var(T_{n,k,a}).$$  Assume the
>   conditions: for some $\delta>0$,
>
> 1. $\lVert{X_{n,i}}_{2+2\delta}\rVert\leq \Delta, \ \forall n,i;$
> 2. For any sequence $b_n$ that tends to infinity with $n$, $\sup_a\lvert{\sigma_{n,b_n,a}^2-\sigma^2}\rvert\to 0$ as
>      $n\to\infty$;
> 3. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^2\alpha_n^{\delta/(\delta+4)}(k)\leq K, \ \forall n$
>
> where $\Delta,K$ are finite constants, independent of $n,k$ or $a$.
>   Then $$T_{n,d_n,1}\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2), \text{ i.e., }
>  d_n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^{dn} X_{n,i}\to N(0,\sigma^2).$$

In the proof, only a specific choice of $b_n$ were used. In the proposition I want to apply this CLT, it is only assumed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_{n,b_n,1}^2=\sigma^2$ as $n\to \infty$ exists.
I'm thinking that it is insufficient to fullfil condition 2. What do you think?